# how to bind dynamically created element in a function to another dynamically created element in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui

I have two functions one that creates an image preview for each image uploaded and another one that clones the input file if the user clicks on choose file button to prevent the previous file from being removed.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzLshnde/5/)**

this is the image preview function

```
var multiImgPreview = function(input, imgPreviewPlaceholder) {

    if (input.files) {
     $("#multipleImageUpload").on("change", function(e) {
        var filesAmount = input.files.length;

        for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(event) {
                $("<span class=\"pip\">" + 
                "<span class=\"remove_icon\">Remove</span>" +
                "<img src=\"" + event.target.result + "\" title=\"" + "\"/>" +
                "</span>").appendTo(imgPreviewPlaceholder);
 
                $(".remove_icon").click(function(){
                   $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
                 }); 
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
        }
      });
    }
};
```

and this is the clone function

```
$(document).on('click', '#multipleImageUpload', function() {
    
    // add to preview
    multiImgPreview(this, 'div.imgPreview');
    
    //clone
    
    var originalInput = $(this), cloned = originalInput.clone();
    
    // move
    originalInput.attr("id", Date.now());
    originalInput.removeClass('multipleImageUpload');
    originalInput.appendTo($('#multipleFilesPH'));
    
    cloned.attr("id", "multipleImageUpload");
    cloned.insertAfter($('#multipleFilesPH'));

    originalInput = null;
    cloned = null;

});
```

the issue here is when I click remove it only removes the preview of the image and not the input cloned, how to dynamically bind the cloned input to the image preview in order to remove the image and never send it to the server?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be best for you to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/Tour It may be best to select an answer to a question before posting another question, You will also want to supply a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You are moving the origin input into `multipleFilesPH`, why? Anyway, is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/moshfeu/d6Lqyo5u/3/) what you are looking for?

Comment: @MoshFeu I'm moving it because by default if the user clicked again on choose file it'll remove the previous files. and yes this is what i'm looking for but it causes errors because of the moving